# How can I play Quake on OS X 10.7 or above?

Tags: macos, quake

Is there any option for native playing Quake on OS X 10.7 and above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes there is actually a way to play Quake but you'll need the CD contents of the original Quake (or play a shareware version).

Personally I have only been able to get this to work using [GLQuake/Quake](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/6388/quake-x) provided by that link.

**REQUIREMENTS**

```
Intel
Mac OS X 10.6 or later
Quake 1 (shareware or retail version).
```

You can download [shareware quake By ID Software (6.7 MB) here](http://www.quakeone.com/q1files/downloads/mac/Quake106SW_DATA.sit). (which is free)

Steps to install:

1. install the quake client from [here](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/6388/quake-x)
2. download the shareware version of quake [here](http://www.quakeone.com/q1files/downloads/mac/Quake106SW_DATA.sit)
3. unzip the .sit file (to a known area)
4. then open up glquake
5. it will ask you to locate the ID1 folder, find it (it should have PAK0.PAK in it).
6. It will load if correctly found ID1 folder is selected
7. Press the green play button
8. Have fun playing old school quake!

Comment: Does local LAN play work with this method?  What about with Windows PCs on the same LAN?

Answer (score 5):

Once you have the original disk and its files, you can choose from a number of modern, maintained [Quake clients](http://quakeone.com/files/1-quake-clients/). From that list, the Mac-native ones are ProQuake+, ProQuake v3.5 (GL), Fitzquake SDL, and Darkplaces.

That page also provides a link to the original, ancient GLQuake, but it's neither modern nor maintained. It'll do the job, but the others are all improvements on GLQuake and will probably serve you better.

Answer (score 2):

In 2018 follow the accepted answer, but you're better off using quakespasm instead of quake-x, you can download it here:

http://quakespasm.sourceforge.net/download.htm

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, the best way to play Quake 1 on a modern Mac (at least if you want to play the single-player campaign; I don't know about network play) is [the Mac Source Ports build of vkQuake](https://macsourceports.com/game/quake). This is QuakeSpasm ported from OpenGL to Vulkan; it runs great on my late Intel Mac mini running Monterey.

You'll need:

- vkQuake, from the above link
- Quake 1's data files; namely, the id1 folder containing pak0.pak and pak1.pak
- (Optional) Quake's music as MP3 or FLAC files, or any other ten songs you'd like to use as a substitute Quake soundtrack

Create a folder named “Quake” to put all these things in.

For the game data files, I have Quake 1 for Classic Mac, so I mounted my image of that CD-ROM in SheepShaver (a Mac OS 9 VM), installed Quake there, and then copied the id1 folder through the portal into the modern world. Getting it from the GOG or Steam releases may be another option if you have a Windows machine. If nothing else, you could use the shareware version just to get it working.

If you have a physical Quake 1 CD-ROM, it's also an audio CD. Rip it using iTunes/Music.app; you need to import it as MP3 (AAC won't work; FLAC will but iTunes doesn't support that). Rename the MP3 files to “track02.mp3”, “track03.mp3”, etc., and put them in id1/music.

(Yes, the first MP3 file is “track02.mp3”. Track 1 of the CD is the data track, containing the game. Tracks 2 through 11 are the music tracks.)

Put the MP3 files into a folder named music; put the music folder into the id1 folder you grabbed from your Quake installation; and put that and vkQuake.app into your Quake folder.

You should have:

- Quake

  - id1

    - music

      - track02.mp3
      - ⋮
      - track11.mp3
    - pak0.pak
    - pak1.pak
  - vkQuake.app

Now you're all set up. Run vkQuake.app whenever you want to play Quake.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, unless you absolutely have to run it on the desktop or you want source ports, the easiest way is [NetQuake](https://www.netquake.io/)